# Looking for a specific Harry Potter fanfic where Harry stays with Snape during the summer of 2nd year

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I'm looking for a Harry Potter fanfic, which I had been reading on fanfiction.net. It's AU starting in the summer of Harry's second year. Harry has to stay with Snape during the summer at Hogwarts. I remember that Snape doesn't wasn't Harry in his rooms so he puts him in an attic and leaves him to his own devices. Harry sleeps on a sofa, which used to be in the teacher's lounge but Lockheart had split pink/violet ink on it. Snape goes to check on Harry to find that he has made a little den type room out of old and broken furniture.

That's as much as I can remember, thanks for any help.

Comment: You might consider rewriting your title to be more specific. Right now it sounds like you're asking for a suggestion of any fan fic... But it looks like you're trying to ID a specific one that you read before?

Comment: Hey there. This site isn't for identifying fan fic (especially fan fic that doesn't feature sci-fi or fantasy, which your description doesn't indicate the fic you're looking for does). I'd suggest trying the [*Help! I'm looking for...*](http://forums.fictionalley.org/park/forumdisplay.php?s=95bbe5dcdc7aef963097b64c7494ecea&forumid=19) forum at [Fiction Alley](http://forums.fictionalley.org/park/), which is a wonderful, and sizable, fic archive dedicated to *Harry Potter* fan fiction. You might have better luck there. :)

Comment: @Slytherincess Sorry, this is incorrect. Fanfic identification questions [are on topic](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9193/are-fanfic-identification-questions-on-topic-on-sff?lq=1) according to consensus on meta (provided it's SF/F fanfic, such as HP, of course).

Comment: Does the title make more sense now?

Comment: @Randal'Thor -- Yes. The OP's description of the fic in question doesn't seem to highlight any sci-fi or fantasy themes per se; simply being set in the HP universe doesn't mean a fic will feature sci-fi or fantasy (although one might think it would!). Regardless, I was trying to point the OP to an archive with a search tool that may be more useful to them. :)

Comment: @anaranjada -- Yes, as Rand al'Thor has already pointed out. Unfortunately, too much time has passed for me to edit my comment. I don't want to delete it because it does have a useful link in it. :)

Comment: @Slytherincess I have tried the forum at Fiction Alley, and numerous googling of key words in my attempt to find this fic and I then stumbled upon this site and found that many others that have had good luck in identifying Harry Potter fics, I thought that I may have a go and getting an answer.

Comment: I highlighted the phrase "Harry has to stay with Snape" from your question and and sent it to Google. It had a [couple hits that look like Harry spending the summer with Snape.](https://www.google.com/search?q=Harry+has+to+stay+with+Snape&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: I am going to close this question due to the easily researched answer: https://www.fanfiction.net/s/861208/1/Summer-With-Snape

Comment: I didn't know we did away with "general reference." As far as I am concerned if I can find the answer to a question that is easily answered (especially in the case of an identification question such as this) I am going to call it a day. No need to waste anyone else's time on a question like this one.

Comment: @ThaddeusHowze but is that actually the answer? it could be another fic with a similar storyline...

Comment: @ThaddeusHowze FWIW, I spent ten minutes or so searching for the answer to this on the internet and couldn't find it. And my Google-fu is fairly good, so it can't be *that* easy to find! Why not post that as an answer rather than a comment, and downvote if you feel the question is bad? While I personally don't like questions like this, it is on-topic for the site, and I can't understand why people want it closed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### This is "[The Guardian, the Ward and the Convict](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/4958520/2/The-Guardian-the-Ward-and-the-Convict)"

Harry spends the summer with Snape after the end of his second year:

> "I'd rather spend the Summer with Snape." Harry's personal hells are
>   swapped - summer with the Dursley's may not be much fun but surely
>   summer with Snape will be worse? AU end of second book--- NOT SLASH

There is a couch that has been covered in ink by Gilderoy Lockhart:

> There were a fair few stained items as well, including
>   a huge couch sticking out from one wall. It was covered with a dust
>   sheet, and when Harry lifted the sheet cautiously to peer underneath
>   he discovered a stain that covered most of the couch in garish ink; a
>   closer examination proved it to be the sort that Lockhart had
>   favoured. The stain was unsightly in the extreme, which was probably
>   why it was in the attic. When Harry sat on the couch though, he
>   discovered it was the most comfortable thing he'd ever encountered,
>   and when he lay down it was more than big enough to serve as a bed.

As the previous paragraph indicates, there is plenty of "old and broken furniture."

And yes, Snape does put Harry in an attic:

> Behind the door were three rough steps, a landing with a second door,
>   and then two more steps. He opened the door at the top of the fifth
>   step and entered what appeared to be an attic. The room was round, and
>   the view showed that he was quite high up on the roof, possibly in one
>   of the smaller towers that sprouted off the main spires. He glanced
>   back at the five shallow steps he'd climbed from the foyer and grinned
>   again.